# Multiply input text by 2, answer in another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN21O.jpg)
[image]

UPDATED:

Here is my whole HTML page. Some of the bottom has been cut due to character limitations here. It is simply repeated many times to get the desired result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-expenses.css">
<title>CashdUp - Expenses</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("input").keyup(function(){

var getInId = $(this).attr('id');
var getOutId = $('#'+getInId+'_ans').attr('id');
var getInVal = document.getElementById(getInId).value; 

 if(!isNaN(getInVal)){   

  var result = (getInVal * 2);

   $('#'+getOutId).val(result);


 }
 else{
    $('#'+getOutId).val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
 }
});

</script>

</head>
<body class="site-body">

    <div class="div-1">

        <h1 class="message">Expenses</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="div-2">

        <table class="left-table" style="width:50%">

            <th><u>Expense</u></th>
            <th><u>Weekly</u></th>
            <th><u>Fortnightly</u></th>
            <th><u>Yearly</u></th>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1_a" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="input1_a_ans" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="outyear1_a" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

        </table>

        <table class="right-table" style="width:50%">

            <th><u>Expense</u></th>
            <th><u>Weekly</u></th>
            <th><u>Fortnightly</u></th>
            <th><u>Yearly</u></th>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                    <select class="expense-option">
                        <option>- Select Option -</option>
                        <option>Car Insurance</option>
                        <option>Car Loan</option>
                        <option>Car Park</option>
                        <option>Car Registration</option>
                        <option>Car Servicing</option>
                        <option>Clothes</option>
                        <option>Credit Card</option>
                        <option>Dining Out</option>
                        <option>Donation</option>
                        <option>Entertainment</option>
                        <option>Groceries</option>
                        <option>Health Insurance</option>
                        <option>Internet</option>
                        <option>Mobile Phone</option>
                        <option>Petrol</option>
                        <option>Rent / Mortgage</option>
                        <option>Spending / Pocket Money</option>
                        <option>Sport</option>
                        <option>Utilities</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                        <input class="expense-option-manual" type="text" placeholder="Expense">
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="options">
                        <input class="expense-option-manual" type="text" placeholder="Expense">
                </td>

                <td><input class="amount" id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output1" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="amount" id="output2" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>  

            </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Some of the bottom has been cut.

UPDATE:

I have now also updated all of my ID's so that they are different.

```
<td><input class="amount" id="week_a" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
<td><input class="amount1" id="outfort_a_ans" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
<td><input class="amount1" id="outyear_a" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>
```

They span from the letter 'a' to the letter 't' to set them apart.

So how then would I implement a multiplication where in every table row I have the input "week_a" through to "week_t" multiply the number in it by the number 2 and have that answer placed in the corresponding row that it was entered into, e.g. if the number 2.56 was placed in week_g then the answer would be in outfort_g_ans as 5.12 e.t.c Then to make it even more complicated have the number 5.12 be multiplied by 26 and have that number show up in outyear_g as 133.12.

Comment: You need to share a real(complete) html sample... looks like you have this structure repeated... in that case ID selector won't work.. .you will have to use class selector with relative element lookup... also might have to use a dom ready handler

Comment: Beware of this `with all the same ID's`, as ID should always be unique. Otherwise only the first matched element are returned and affected

Comment: you want to do it for multiple id which is different i.e. input1 goes to output1, input2 goes to output2 right?

Comment: <td></td> are columns not rows and all  columns are in same row; finally rows are repeated for 19 times am i right, If they are rows then it can fixed

Comment: @cracker input1 multiples by 2 and goes to output1.
Output1 would then have that value multiplied by 26 and the answer would be in output2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working **[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/reWbYN?editors=1010)**

your Code issue with same `ID` for all textbox. `ID` is always **Unique.**

so i change some editing on your code,

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var getInId = $(this).attr('id');
    var getOutId = $('#'+getInId+'_ans').attr('id');
    var getInVal = document.getElementById(getInId).value; 

    if(!isNaN(getInVal)){   
        var result = (getInVal * 2);
        $('#'+getOutId).val(result);
    }
    else{
        $('#'+getOutId).val("");
        alert("Please enter a valid number");
    }
});
```

### Updated  **[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/mPOZBV?editors=1010)**

```
<td><input class="amount" id="input_c" type="text" placeholder="Weekly $"></td>
<td><input class="amount" id="input_c_ans" type="text" placeholder="Fortnightly $" readonly></td>
<td><input class="amount" id="input_c_year" type="text" placeholder="Yearly $" readonly></td>
```

Script Here,

```
 var yearResult = (result * 26);
 $('#'+getOutyear).val(yearResult);
```

Comment: I tried this with no result. Like a few have said it must be an ID issue. Since all 3 inputs in each row share the same ID throughout the whole table (e.g. 20 share the ID of input1, 20 share the ID of output1 and 20 share the ID of output2). Would it be a better idea to rename the classes of them? If so, how would my JS look to have it so that only the table row is changed by the input within that row rather than have it change others of influence others. Trying to figure out how to get it to work so that each row is influenced by its own row's data input and not anothers.

Comment: I've just re-looked at your code. I never changed the ID's names in mine, hence why the JS didn't work. I'll try it now.

Comment: And also just to cut to the chase. If I then wanted to have it so that the ID="input1_a_ans" input had its figure multipled by 26 and that answer placed into the input ID of id="outyear1_a". How would the JS look?

Comment: I've changed all of my ID's so that they are now unique. Are you able to assist with the code? Please refer to the original post for the updates.

Comment: Textbox ID's still not unique. Here now your current Code  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/mPOZBV?editors=1010) . enter input first 3 textbox. its works.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated everything to how you have shown me. I can see that it works in the demo, but mine still doesn't. Must be something getting in the way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've figured it out. I had been placing the <script> in the head tag, with no success. I then placed it in the body at the top, but still no success. I've now placed it at the end of the body and it has worked. I was under the impression that scripts had to be at the start in the head or in the body at the start. Learning curve indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having trouble because `#input1` doesn't exist at the time the code in your `<script>` is run. Place it in a document ready handler instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#input1").keyup(function(){
   var input1 = parseInt($("#input1").val());
   if(!isNaN(input1)){
      $("#output1").val(input1 * 2);
   }
   else{
     $("#output1").val("");
     alert("Please enter a valid number");
   }
  });
});
```

> the above table data is repeated at least 19 times with all the same ID's and classes.

I hope you mean you are increasing the number for each row. Your id tag should be unique in the entire HTML document.

Comment: This code has had some results. Like a few have said my issue is the ID. Would it be better to use the Class then to get a result? If so how would I go about doing it.

Comment: The first row was influenced but nothing else was when I placed numbers into the others. Also, if I put in a decimal point how would I have the decimal point number multiplied by 2?